# How to create a patch from clearcase snapshot view?

Tags: diff, clearcase, patch, snapshot

I referred "How to create a patch for a directory in ClearCase?" . My question is extension of this. I have a snapshot view, which points to a projects branch. I updated the view and some files got updated. Now how can I create a zip file of these updated files (including directory structure), so that I can unzip the file to desired location, and updated files gets copied there.

Comment: ok.. So is there any way to get the zip from directories. Lets say we dont bother about clearcase view now. But once the update view is done, we should be able to scan the view physical directory and get the latest files, something like that....

Comment: Yes, simply zip your current updated snapshot view folder.

Answer (score 0):

A diff patch required a known base. Unless you set a label on your view just before the `cleartool update` (or `setcs -current`), you won't be able to produce a patch (the state of the view *before* the update would be lo.

You would need to parse the log produced by a cleartool update in order to zip only those files and unzip (override) said files to your destination folder.

> So is there any way to get the zip from directories. Lets say we dont bother about clearcase view now. But once the update view is done, we should be able to scan the view physical directory and get the latest files, something like that

Since you just updated your snapshot view, the folder content represent the files at the right versions (ie, at the versions selected by the config spec)

All you need to do is zip the root view folder, and you can unzip (override) its content somewhere else.